# avoid installing all the node_modules dependencies each time in CI environment

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gradle, npm

I have multiple modules in my project and only one of them is node project. I use then [`gradle-node-plugin`](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin) to integrate with the rest of the modules. Since I use jenkins for CI and I want jenkins to do full wipe of project directory and checkout recent version each time default behaviour is that `npm install` (here via `gradle-node-plugin` `npmInstall` wrapper but the same situation is for plain npm) downloads all the dependencies each time CI rebuild has been triggered.

I wonder if it is possible either install the `package.json` dependencies somewhere globally (eg in case of `gradle-node-plugin` in `.gradle/nodejs/<node-dist>/lib/node_modules/` or keep `node_modules` outside the build tree (eg in jenkins workspace folder).

**Edit:**

Since all the node dependency set in the project actually takes about 300MB, proxy-caching seems no to be sufficient because of few factors - size, time needed to resolve all of them and also some dependencies needs to be even recompiled after downloading (eg socket-io). For the time being we're using workaround defined in `build.gradle` that moves `node_modules` to the parent folder that will not be cleaned and than use symbolic link. The workaround is activated only in Jenkins environment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to create a  [mirror of the npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-mirror), if so, there is a npm module to do just that

> npm-mirror is a utility for mirroring a subset of npm packages from
>   another npm registry. It syncs all of the dependencies for a
>   particular node module and writes them to the local filesystem so that
>   a simple webserver can behave like a commonjs compliant package
>   registry.

Comment: I was already researching [npm-lazy](http://mixu.net/npm_lazy/) but still resolving all the npm (and actually bower also) dependencies all over again will take some time and it seems like unnecessary task in compare to maven/gradle build system where it is possible to keep dependencies outside the build tree.

Anyway some kind of mirror might be a workaround.